# change default color of telerik:RadGridView from black to to blue

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have a RadGridView using telerik and the default color is black. I was wondering how do I change that color.

```
 <telerik:RadGridView Name="dgData1"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                 AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="0"
                                 ShowGroupPanel="False" 
                                 IsFilteringAllowed="False" 
                                 CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                                 RowIndicatorVisibility ="Collapsed"
                                 IsReadOnly="True"
                                 EnableRowVirtualization="False"
                                 EnableColumnVirtualization="False"
                                 SelectionMode="Single"
                                 Sorting="dgData_Sorting">
            </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add "telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Summer"" to your data grid view.

```
<telerik:RadGridView Name="someName" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Summer"
                                 AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="0"
                                 ShowGroupPanel="False" 
                                 IsFilteringAllowed="False" 
                                 CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                                 RowIndicatorVisibility ="Collapsed"
                                 IsReadOnly="True"
                                 EnableRowVirtualization="False"
                                 EnableColumnVirtualization="False"
                                 SelectionMode="Single"
  </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="Red" Foreground="White" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,36,0,0" Name="radGridView1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewRow}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkOrange"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="EmployeeID" DataMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeID}"/>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Hope this help you.